Keyboardshort for "Generate commit message with Copilot" in VSCode?

In Visual Studio Code , there is a button "Generate commit message with Copilot", I want to click this button by keyboard shortcuts ,
I tried  check commands but didnt find it,
is there any shortcut to trigger this?

The command is github.copilot.git.generateCommitMessage
vscode details where it is working


Version: 1.88.1
Commit: e170252f762678dec6ca2cc69aba1570769a5d39
Date: 2024-04-10T17:34:12.840Z



this problem resolved in latest vscode version.

please say the actual version number. and what is the ID of the command?
